# Node.js: curl: (52) Empty reply from server with space in request not encoded

Tags: node.js, express

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("Hello World\n");
});

server.listen(8000);
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```

I executed following curl commands:

```
curl "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
Hello World

// space is not encoded
curl "http://127.0.0.1:8000/x y"
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

curl "http://127.0.0.1:8000/x"
Hello World

// space is encoded
curl "http://127.0.0.1:8000/x%20y"
Hello World
```

Can you please explain the why I get curl 52???

In this case, I want to send 500 back. Can I do that?

Comment: we need the rest of the node code and the curl command line.  Hopefully there is a res.send in there...

Comment: `app.get('/item/id')` means literally `/item/id` not `/item/item1`

Comment: Try `-I` curl's option for explanation. (On my machine curl sends 2 requests for `curl http://google.com/x y` command: first one to Google Server and second one to `y`.)

Comment: send your request in quotes...without uotes curl sends two requests....by putting in quotes it sends 1 request

Comment: @user2384694 Getting HTTP 400 from Google that way. Node's behaviour on malformed requests is emitting [`clientError`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_clienterror) event (and closing connection by default).

Comment: @elmigranto as the correct answer here.  There doesn't appear to be anyway to hook into the process in this case and do something application specific.  By the time any error events are received, the socket is already in a not writable state.

Answer (score 1):

Even with the missing `res.send` it looks like an issue with your route. you probably meant.

```
app.get('/item/:id', function(...) {
  ..
})
```

Note the `:` before `id`. This creates a variable that can be accessed on req.params.id.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this question in mind as well.
I guess `curl` expects already-encoded url if quoted by double quotes. If it finds whitespace in url, it will consider it an invalid url.

And this is quite different from `wget` command. If you run this:

```
wget "http://127.0.0.1:8000/x y"
```

actually wget encodes the url for you and the request actually will be sent as:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/x%20y
```

These kind of facts really tease our brains.